# Solve IVP in a implicit form

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting, output

```
DSolve[(5 y[x]^4 + 3 y[x]^2 + Exp[y[x]]) D[y[x], x] == 
       Cos[x] && y[0] == 0, y[x], x]
    
(*{{y[x] -> InverseFunction[E^#1 + #1^3 + #1^5 &][1 + Sin[x]]}}*)
```

solves the IVP $(5y^4+3y^2+e^y)y'=\cos x$, $y(0)=0$. Is it possible to have an output in an implicit form, that is, $y^5+y^3+e^y=\sin x+1$, e.g.

```
{{y[x] -> y[x]^5+y[x]^[3]+Exp[y] == Sin[x] + 1}}
```

Comment: In this case it is possible because the answer is in terms of InverseFunction, and you can post-process the answer. In general you’d have to hack the appropriate Solve[] step and then solve for the constants of integration — not easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a way (caveat: it temporarily hobbles an internal function while `DSolve` is running):

```
Block[{DSolve`DSolveSolve = Solve},
 DSolve[
  (5 y[x]^4 + 3 y[x]^2 + Exp[y[x]]) D[y[x], x] == Cos[x] &&
    y[0] == 0, y, x]
 ]

(*  Solve[E^y[x] + y[x]^3 + y[x]^5 == 1 + Sin[x], y[x]]  *)
```

Note that `DSolve` can currently be expected to evolve rather often. It is unknown for just how many versions this hack will continue to work.

*Alternative.*  This should work in all versions. Here's a function I wrote some time ago to convert a solution to an equation (for a broader range of solutions to both `DSolve` and `NDSolve`).  It returns an `Inactive`, as opposed to an inert, `Solve[]` call.

```
ClearAll[toImplicitSolution];
toImplicitSolution::usage = 
  "toImplicitSolution[sol] converts a solution to an implicit solution.";
toImplicitSolution::IRoot = 
  "A Root object is being inverted; extraneous solutions may be introduced.";
toImplicitSolution[sol_] :=
  sol /. {
    HoldPattern[{x_[t_] -> InverseFunction[f_][a_]}] :> 
     Inactive[Solve][f[x[t]] == a, x[t]],
    HoldPattern[{x_ -> Verbatim[Function][{t_}, InverseFunction[f_][a_]]}] :> 
     Inactive[Solve][f[x[t]] == a, x[t]],
    HoldPattern[{x_ -> Verbatim[Function][{t_}, Root[f_, n_]]}] /;
       (Message[toImplicitSolution::IRoot]; True) :> 
     Inactive[Solve][f[x[t]] == 0, x[t]],
    HoldPattern[ff : {(_ -> Verbatim[Function][{t_}, _]) ..}] :> 
     Inactive[Solve][
      Thread[Through[ff[[All, 1]][t]] == Through[ff[[All, 2]][t]]], 
      Through[ff[[All, 1]][t]]],
    HoldPattern[ff : {(_ -> _InterpolatingFunction) ..}] :> 
     Inactive[Solve][
      Thread[Through[ff[[All, 1]][\[FormalT]]] == Through[ff[[All, 2]][\[FormalT]]]], 
      Through[ff[[All, 1]][\[FormalT]]]]};

dsol = DSolve[(5 y[x]^4 + 3 y[x]^2 + Exp[y[x]]) D[y[x], x] == Cos[x] &&
     y[0] == 0, y, x];

toImplicitSolution[dsol]

(*  {Inactive[Solve][E^y[x] + y[x]^3 + y[x]^5 == 1 + Sin[x], y[x]]}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know why Mathematica does not have an option as Maple' s dsolve implicit setting?

Comment: @Dimitris No, I don't.  I suppose you could request it as a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your ode for the function `x[y]`

```
X = DSolveValue[{(5 y ^4 + 3 y ^2 + Exp[y ])  == x'[y] Cos[x[y]],x[0] == 0} , x , y]
(*Function[{y}, -ArcSin[1 - E^y - y^3 - y^5]]*)

Sin[X[y]]
(*-1 + E^y + y^3 + y^5*)
```