# DSolve: lack of implicit option (unlike Maple's dsolve built-in option)

Tags: differential-equations, implicit, maple

I am working with the book '[Differential Equations for Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521194245)' (Cambridge University Press). The author dedicates one chapter of the book in solving ODEs with Maple. The book was published in 2010. Recently I posted a question about [solving an IVP in implicit form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235616/solve-ivp-in-a-implicit-form). User @MichealE2 provided an excellent answer. Nevertheless, I am surprised why Mathematica (without error on my part) does not provide a built-in implicit option unlike Maple which offers such a feature since, at least, 10 years (version 14). Is there a reason that justifies this lack? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you asked WRI, since they make those decisions?

Comment: I also asked for this option long time ago. I hope they will add it in some future version. They just added option for DSolve to show the singular solutions. So they seem to be working on `DSolve` and have not forgotten about it with all the other cloud things WRI is busy with. Note also that `DSolve` can now solve many more ode's than few years ago as well.