# How to get the implicit function solution of ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

For example,

ODE:

$$(2x - 5y + 3)dx - (2x + 4y - 6)dy = 0$$

The implicit function solution:

$$(2x+y-3)^2  (4y-x-3) = C$$

However, if it is solved directly with DSolve, the solution is very complex:

```
Clear[eqn, sol, x, y];
eqn = (2*x - 5*y[x] + 3)*Dt[x] - (2*x + 4*y[x] - 6)*Dt[y[x]] == 0;
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]

(*

    {{y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 1])},
    
     {y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 2])},
    
     {y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 3])},
    
     {y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 4])},
    
     {y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 5])}, 
    
    {y[x] -> (3 - x)/2 + 
        1/(4 Root[
            4 + (-72 + 72 x) #1 + (324 - 648 x + 324 x^2) #1^2 + (864 - 
                 2592 x + 2592 x^2 - 864 x^3) #1^3 + (-7776 + 31104 x - 
                 46656 x^2 + 31104 x^3 - 7776 x^4) #1^4 + (46656 + 
                 729 E^(12 C[1]) - 279936 x + 699840 x^2 - 933120 x^3 + 
                 699840 x^4 - 279936 x^5 + 46656 x^6) #1^6 &, 6])}}
    
    *)
```

Is there any code that can get the implicit function solution of ODE?

The following is the previous question:
For example,

ODE:
$$xy'(x) - y(x) - (y(x)^2 - x^2)^{1/2} = 0$$

Implicit function solution:
$$y+(y^2-x^2)^{1/2}=Cx^2\ (x>0)$$

$$y-(y^2-x^2)^{1/2}=C\ (x<0)$$

If it is solved directly with `DSolve`, the running time is very long and no solution is obtained （Version: 11.3. Updated: After the computer was restarted, the problem was solved. ）:

```
Clear[eqn, sol, x, y];
eqn = x*y'[x] - y[x] - ((y[x])^2 - x^2)^(1/2) == 0;
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
```

Example 2:

```
Clear[eqn, sol, x, y];
eqn = x*y'[x] == y[x]*Log[y[x]/x];
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
```

How to get the implicit function solution of the differential equation?

Comment: There is no option in DSolve to ask for implicit solution. But these ode's are solved immediately in V 13

Comment: I just want to add that they are also solved immediately in V 12. Specifics are `"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: After the computer was restarted, the problem was solved. The Question has been updated.

Comment: The line "Implicit function solution: y[x]+(y[x])^2-x^2)^(1/2)==C[1]*x^2 (x>0)；…" involves typo, please double-check it. Also, you may use $\LaTeX$ to typeset the equation better.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137598/1871

Comment: @xzczd OK. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `y[x] + ((y[x])^2 - x^2)^(1/2) == C[1]*x^2` is a solution?: `y[x] + ((y[x])^2 - x^2)^(1/2) == C[1]*x^2 /. sol /. x -> 12 // FullSimplify`

Comment: @xzczd Yes. x > 0 -- > y'[x] == y[x]/x + Sqrt[(y[x]/x)^2 - 1];
u[x] = y[x]/x;

--> y'[x] == u[x] + x*u'[x];
--> u[x] + x*u'[x] == u[x] + Sqrt[(u[x])^2 - 1];
--> Dt[u[x]]/Sqrt[(u[x])^2 - 1] == Dt[x]/x;
--> Log[Abs[u[x] + Sqrt[(u[x])^2 - 1]]] == Log[Abs[x]] + Log[C[1]];
--> u[x] + Sqrt[(u[x])^2 - 1] == C*x; (Abs[C] = C1);
--> y[x] + Sqrt[(y[x])^2 - x^2] == C*x^2. (x > 0)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235644/4999

Comment: I can't immediately spot the mistake of your deduction, but something is wrong with it. Another numeric verification: `{Table[Solve[y[x] + Sqrt[(y[x])^2 - x^2] == C x^2 /. C -> 1, y[x]], {x, {1, 5}}], 
 NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]/x + Sqrt[(y[x]/x)^2 - 1], y[1] == 1}, y[5], {x, 1, 5}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 16]}`

Comment: If I guess it right, for $C>0$, the solution is correct only if $x>\frac{1}{C}$.

Comment: Iust to compare. The command of Maple 2021 `dsolve(2*x - 5*y(x) + 3 - (2*x + 4*y(x) - 6)*diff(y(x), x) = 0, y(x), implicit)` produces `-(2*ln(-(-3 + y(x) + 2*x)/(x - 1)))/3 - ln((3 - 4*y(x) + x)/(x - 1))/3 - ln(x - 1) - _C1 = 0`.

Comment: Your comments are very helpful to me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Some things change to better. In 13.0.0 on Windows 10

```
Clear[eqn, sol, x, y];eqn = x*y'[x] - y[x] - ((y[x])^2 - x^2)^(1/2) == 0;
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
```

> `{{y[x] -> (-x - x Tanh[1/2 (C[1] + Log[x])]^2)/(-1 +  Tanh[1/2 (C[1] + Log[x])]^2)}}`

```
Clear[eqn, sol, x, y];eqn = x*y'[x] == y[x]*Log[y[x]/x];
sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
```

> `{{y[x] -> E^(1 + E^C[1] x) x}}`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: After the computer was restarted, the problem was solved. The Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hacky way to intercept the last `Solve` that `DSolve` calls in V13 (warning: the behavior of `DSolve` may change in future):

```
eqn = x*y'[x] - y[x] - ((y[x])^2 - x^2)^(1/2) == 0;
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
 Unprotect@Solve;
 Solve[e_, y[x], opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   Inactive[Solve][e, y[x], opts]]; (* Return[e, DSolve]; *)
 Protect@Solve;
 sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]
 ]
```

> [image]

```
% // First // Activate
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{y[x] -> (-x - x Tanh[1/2 (C[1] + Log[x])]^2)/
>        (-1 + Tanh[1/2 (C[1] + Log[x])]^2)}}
> *)
> ```

Comment: You seem to have to use `Return[..]` for the OP's `Dt[]` example. Also, it doesn't work on IVPs; need to solve for parameters after, if possible.

Comment: Thank you! @Michael E2